# Numpy resize without modifying original object

Tags: python, numpy

I want to expand dimensions of two tables so I can use numpy's broadcast multiply on them. I used the following code:

```
def tableResize(table1,table2,var1,var2):
    n1=[1]*len(var1)
    n2=[1]*len(var2)
    table1.resize(list(table1.shape)+n2)
    table2.resize(n1+list(table2.shape))
    return table1,table2
```

Lets say table1 is 2*3 and table2 is 3*4, the expanded tables will be 2*3*1*1 and 1*1*3*4.
Although I noticed that I can write

```
table1[:,:,np.newaxis,np.newaxis]*table2[np.newaxis,np.newaxis,:,:]
```

This won't have any effect on table1 and table2 themselves. But I dont know how to generate the list `[:,:,np.newaxis,np.newaxis]` automatically.

However, the resize method doesn't have return value and it will modify the object itself. I don't want to use deepcopy. Anyone have ideas? Thanks a lot^_^

Comment: `A.reshape` returns an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However, the `resize` method doesn't have return value and it will modify the object itself.

Yes, but if you look at [the docs for the `resize` method](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.resize.html#numpy.ndarray.resize) it gives you the answer: the [`resize` function](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.resize.html#numpy.resize).

There are many pairs like this in NumPy, where `np.spam(a, eggs)` makes a spamified copy of `a`, while `a.spam(eggs)` spamifies `a` in-place. If you look at the docs, they'll be linked together.

So, I think what you're looking for is:

```
t1 = np.resize(table1, list(table1.shape)+n2)
t2 = np.resize(table2, n1+list(table2.shape))
return t1, t2
```

Comment: Cool! Haven't noticed this before but this really help a lot! Thanks!

Comment: `np.resize` is not linked to `a.resize`.  Depending on parameters it can end up using `concatenate`.  `np.reshape` is one of those functions that uses its corresponding `a.reshape` method.  I don't think there are many in-place methods.

Comment: @hpaulj Yes it is linked to `a.resize`. Click on either method's docs (I linked both in the answer), and they have see also links to the other one.

Comment: Yes the docs do link the two, but the code does not.  For reference I added that to my answer.

Comment: @hpaulj: You may be right that `resize` isn't what he wants, in either form. I'm actually not clear on what he wants from the question—he seems to not want a deep copy, but also not want to modify the originals in-place, so… And you're right that he isn't actually resizing anything, but I'm not sure what he _is_ trying to do. I think this is what he asked for: something like `a.resize` but not in-place. Your answer seems like a good guess at what he _should have_ asked for (better than what I could guess, at least:).

Answer (score 1):

`a1 = a.reshape(...)` returns a view - `a1` has a new shape, but shares the data buffer.

```
a1 = table1.reshape(table1.shape+(1,)*table2.ndim)
 # (2, 3, 1, 1)

b1 = table2.reshape((1,)*table1.ndim+table2.shape)
 # (1, 1, 3, 4)
```

Since dimensions are added at the start as needed, `table2` does not need to be expanded.

```
a1 + b1 == a1 + table2
```

Take a look at `np.atleast_3d` and `np.broadcast_arrays` for other ideas on how to expand the dimensions of arrays.

---

Looking further at `resize`, I'd say that it, in either form, is the wrong function to use when all you want to do is add are singleton dimensions.  `reshape` is the correct function/method.  Either that or `np.newaxis`.

---

You can build `[:,:,np.newaxis,np.newaxis]` by concatenating slices and `None`:

```
s=[slice(None)]*2 + [None]*2
# [slice(None, None, None), slice(None, None, None), None, None]

table1[s].shape
# (2, 3, 1, 1)
```

---

`np.resize` code:

```
File:        /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py
def resize(a, new_shape):

    if isinstance(new_shape, (int, nt.integer)):
        new_shape = (new_shape,)
    a = ravel(a)
    Na = len(a)
    if not Na: return mu.zeros(new_shape, a.dtype.char)
    total_size = um.multiply.reduce(new_shape)
    n_copies = int(total_size / Na)
    extra = total_size % Na

    if total_size == 0:
        return a[:0]

    if extra != 0:
        n_copies = n_copies+1
        extra = Na-extra

    a = concatenate( (a,)*n_copies)
    if extra > 0:
        a = a[:-extra]

    return reshape(a, new_shape)
```

`np.reshape` code (typical of functions the delegate to an array method):

```
File:        /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py
def reshape(a, newshape, order='C'):
    try:
        reshape = a.reshape
    except AttributeError:
        return _wrapit(a, 'reshape', newshape, order=order)
    return reshape(newshape, order=order)
```

Compare the timings for the 2 functions - `resize` is much slower.

```
In [109]: timeit np.resize(a,(2,3,1,1)).shape
10000 loops, best of 3: 41.5 µs per loop

In [110]: timeit np.reshape(a,(2,3,1,1)).shape
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.79 µs per loop
```

The in-place `resize` is fast:

```
In [124]: %%timeit a1=a.copy()
a1.resize((2,3,1,1))
a1.shape
   .....: 
1000000 loops, best of 3: 799 ns per loop
```